# Set 'Eclipse Kepler default theme ' to Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, ide

Good morning. Exists some way for set the Kepler default theme to Luna? Eclipse Luna themes really sucks.

This is the Kepler default theme:

[image: Kepler default theme]

This is the classic Luna theme (looks equals that 'Windows 7 classic'):

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Change in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Theme:Classic`

Comment: @Egi G. Thanks for comment. I don't want Classic theme in Luna. I want the 'Eclipse Kepler default theme' (see the picture) for Eclipse Luna. Thanks for comment (Y)

Comment: Strange. My Luna has the same design as kepler. What is the diffrence in your Luna?

Comment: I updated the post. I added the image of the 'classic theme' of Luna. It's really stranger, why you have the kepler theme and me not?

Comment: I have the Windows 7 Classic design selected and have the same design as for kepler. Besides the "rounded" transitions in the tabs

Comment: Thanks for reply again bro. What version you have? Eclipse for Java EE, for Java, for PHP or for C++? You used Windows or Linux? I'll try dowloading again maybe.

Comment: i have Classic Eclipse

Comment: Ok bro. I think this is for the version of Eclipse. I used Eclipse JEE. Anyway i'll try downloading again Luna. Thanks for everything (sorry for the reputation, i can't give you :( )

Comment: No problem. I hope re-download will help.